# Why doesn't this queue work in multiprocessing?(append() method in function body)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue, python-multiprocessing

I am working to build a script with multiprocessing. 
But while implementing the queue, I found out it doesn't work as I expected and still don't know why.

Here is my pseudo code which consists of three parts:
a function for making sentences list from strings, 
strings list and outcome list for appending sentences,
and the main code for implementing queue and multiprocessing.

```
def process_string(que_object):

    while que_object.empty():
       time.sleep(2)

    q = que_object.get(timeout=2)
    sentence = "Here is your string_"+q
    print(sentence)
    final_sentence.append(sentence)

strings =["alskfj","alksjf"...]
final_sentences = []

if __name__ == "__main__":

    que_object = Queue()
    for i in strings:
        que_object.put(strings[strings.index(i)])
        #print(strings[strings.index(i)])
    #print(que_object)

    with Manager() as manager:
        L = manager.list(strings)
        process_list =[]
        for i in range(2):
            p = Process(target =process_string,args=(que_obejct,))
            process_list.append(p)
            p.start()
        for i in range(2):

            p.join()
            #time.sleep(1)
        print(final_sentences)
```

Comment: Isn't it multithreading that you want ? (instead of multiprocessing) https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html

Comment: @BenoîtZu Thank you so much for your comment and suggestion; As far as I know multiprocessing is said to be "safe" because it doesn't share memory space so I started with multiprocessing and I want to ensure racing condition doesn't happen at all.  But isn't it possible to use queue with multiprocessing too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`multiprocessing.Process`es are, as the name suggests, seperate OS level processes.  therefore when you do `final_sentence.append` this is being done in the memory/address space of another process and hence isn't visible to the process that does the `print(final_sentences)`

I'd suggest using a `Pool` and `map`ping the function over your data as in the first example [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion and solution as to why my code didn't work!:) I think your specific advice will help other beginner-level users like me so I will edit my title accordingly. Thank you again!